# Proof of Set Intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I'm trying to prove that $\bigcap\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left(\frac{2}{n}, \frac{3n+5}{n+1}\right) = (0,3)$. I'm finding myself stuck in my attempt, even though it makes sense intuitively because $\frac{2}{n}$ decreases, as a sequence, to $0$ and $\frac{3n+5}{n+1}$ decreases to $3$. I'll post my attempt below. I'm hoping also for some feedback on the proof-writing style.

**Attempted Proof that $\bigcap\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left(\frac{2}{n}, \frac{3n+5}{n+1}\right) \subset (0,3)$**

Let $x \in \bigcap\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left(\frac{2}{n}, \frac{3n+5}{n+1}\right)$. For every $n$, we have $x > \frac{2}{n} > 0$. Furthermore, for each $n$,
$$ 
x < \frac{3n+5}{n+1} = \frac{(3n + 3) + 2}{n+1} = \frac{3(n+1)}{n+1} + \frac{2}{n+1} = 3 + \frac{2}{n+1}. 
$$
I'm trying to show that $x < 3$. I tried to proceed by contradiction. Suppose that $x \geq 3$. Then $x - 3 \geq 0$. Let $y = 3 - x$. I want to pick an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ in the above statement (since it holds for every $n$) such that $\frac{2}{n+1} \leq y$. If I do that, then I have $x < 3 + \frac{2}{n+1} \leq 3 + y = 3 + (x-3) = x$, so $x < x$, which is a contradiction. I can solve for $n$ as follows:
\begin{align*} 
\frac{2}{n+1} \leq y & \iff \frac{n+1}{2} \geq \frac{1}{y} \\
& \iff n \geq \frac{2}{y} - 1 \\
& \iff n \geq \frac{2}{3-x} - 1.
\end{align*}
Therefore, if $x \geq 3$, we have $x < x$, which is a contradiction, so $x < 3$. So $0 < x < 3$, we get the first inclusion.

**Attempted Proof that $\bigcap\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left(\frac{2}{n}, \frac{3n+5}{n+1}\right) \supset (0,3)$**

Let $x \in (0,3)$. Then $0 < x < 3$. I want to show that $\frac{2}{n} < x < \frac{3n+5}{n+1}$ for every $n$. First, we have
$$ 
x < 3 = \frac{3n}{n} < \frac{3n+5}{n}, 
$$
which is as far as I can get in showing that $x < \frac{3n+5}{n+1}$. I can't figure out how to prove $x > \frac{2}{n}$. I could try contradiction. So suppose that $x \leq \frac{2}{n}$ for some $n$. I'd then want to "take limits" and conclude that $x \leq 0$, which isn't possible. Since this is only a single $n$, I can't choose a particular $n$ that gives a contradiction.

I'd appreciate any guidance on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The first interval in the intersection is $(2,4)$ and if that is *intersected* with the rest of the intervals, the intersection will be a subset of $(2,4)$ so will not be what you're trying to show.

Answer (score 0):

Your result is false. Let $U_n = (2/n, \frac{3n+5}{n+1})$.
We have $1\notin U_1$. So $1\notin \cap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} U_n \subset U_1$..

Your intuition is that:
Let $a, b$ be two real numbers and let $(a_n)$ be a decreasing sequence to $a$, s.t $a_n > a$, and $(b_n)$ an increasing sequence to $b$, s.t $b_n<b$, then
$\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} (a_n,b_n) = ]a, b[$.

A similar result with intersection, if $(a_n)$ is an increasing sequence to $a$ and $(b_n)$ a decreasing sequence to $b$, then $\cap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(a_n,b_n) = [a,b]$.

Comment: But $0$ is not in $(0,3)$ anyway.

Comment: Yes right, changed $0$ with $1$.

Comment: @ylefay Does that result with intersections you mentioned still work if both $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are decreasing? Because in that case, I'd have $\bigcap\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left(\frac{2}{n}, \frac{3n+5}{n+1}\right) = [0,3]$, which is still incorrect because it contains $1$.

Comment: If both series are decreasing then $\cup_{n\in\mathbb{n}}] a_n, b_n[ = ]a_1, b]$.